# Using VBA to Automate - Save multiple attachment based on multiple criteria to specific folders

Tags: vba, outlook

I send daily reports to multiple stakeholders (~10), based on the following criteria

- Criteria 1: Download attachments based on senders and 1 or 2 keywords from email sender and subject
- Criteria 2: Exclude weekends as reports are only sent to and responded from respective stakeholders on the weekdays.
  Monday reports are downloaded from Friday's attachment
- Criteria 3: One company has 4 regions, the remaining are centralized.
  Attachments from the company with 4 regions,are to be saved in a folder under the company title.
  With the remaining companies, attachments are saved in their respective company folder name.
  Files will be more descriptive with year, month and day as opposed to the parenting folder limited to Company name and **year and month only**.

All the above has been attempted. I also need to create automation where each folder will hold files maxing 2 months only after which another folder would be created for attachments of those months.

I appreciate my code is clunky and would need a faster version.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveOutlookAttachments()

    Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

    'For Folders creation

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dir As Scripting.Folders
    Dim dirFolderName As String


    'For Date settings
    Dim iBackdate As Integer

    ' Hardcoding Partners - 
    Dim COMP_A_North As String
    Dim COMP_A_South As String
    Dim COMP_A_East As String
    Dim COMP_A_West As String
    Dim COMP_B As String
    Dim COMP_C As String
    Dim COMP_D As String
    Dim COMP_E As String
    Dim COMP_F As String


    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox")


    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject


    'Setting Partner Filters
 
    COMP_A_North = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compa%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Scotland%'"
    COMP_A_South = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compa%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%North%'"
    COMP_A_East = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compa%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Midlands%'"
    COMP_A_West = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compa%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%London%'"
    COMP_B = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compb%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Missing%'"
    COMP_C = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compc%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Missing%'"
    COMP_D = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compd%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Missing%'"
    COMP_E = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%compe%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Missing%'"
    COMP_F = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@compf%'" & "AND 
    ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%Missing%'"

 
        For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_A_North)

        'Check Item Class
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

          'Set as Mail Item
           Set objMailItem = objItem

           With objMailItem
              Select Case Weekday(Now)
                  Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                      iBackdate = 3
                  Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                    iBackdate = 4
                  Case Else ' Other days
                    iBackdate = 2
                 End Select

            ' Check date
            If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                    ' Save Attachments
                    
                If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "compa  Report UpTo" & 
                Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                  If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                      Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                  Else
                      Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                  End If
                
                
                
                    For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        
        
                        
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
        objAttachment.FileName = "compa North and Iceland Region Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy- 
         mm- dd")   'Put in a valid folder location to store attachements


                    Next
                
                End If
            
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next




        For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_A_South)

        'Check Item Class
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

            'Set as Mail Item
             Set objMailItem = objItem

            With objMailItem
                Select Case Weekday(Now)
                    Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                        iBackdate = 3
                    Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                        iBackdate = 4
                    Case Else ' Other days
                        iBackdate = 2
                End Select

                ' Check date
                If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                    ' Save Attachments
                    If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                    dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "compa  Report 
                    UpTo" & Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                    If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                        Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                    Else
                        Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                    End If
                        
                        
                            For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                            Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, 
                            objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
                            objAttachment.FileName = "compa South Region  Report" & 
                            Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in a valid folder location to 
                            store attachements

                        Next

                End If
                
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next


    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_A_East)

        'Check Item Class
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

            'Set as Mail Item
            Set objMailItem = objItem

            With objMailItem
                Select Case Weekday(Now)
                    Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                        iBackdate = 3
                    Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                        iBackdate = 4
                    Case Else ' Other days
                        iBackdate = 2
                End Select

                ' Check date
                If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                    ' Save Attachments
                    If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                    dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "compa  Report 
                UpTo" & Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                    If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                        Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                    Else
                        Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                    End If
                        
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
    objAttachment.FileName = "compa East Region  Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in 
    a valid folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                End If
                
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next




    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_A_West)

        'Check Item Class
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

            'Set as Mail Item
            Set objMailItem = objItem

            With objMailItem
                Select Case Weekday(Now)
                    Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                        iBackdate = 3
                    Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                        iBackdate = 4
                    Case Else ' Other days
                        iBackdate = 2
                End Select

                ' Check date
                If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                    ' Save Attachments
                    If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                    dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "compa  Report 
    UpTo" & Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                End If
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
      objAttachment.FileName = "compa West and Central Region  Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm- 
      dd")   'Put in a valid folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                        
                End If
                
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next




    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_B)

        'Check Item Class
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

            'Set as Mail Item
            Set objMailItem = objItem

            With objMailItem
                Select Case Weekday(Now)
                    Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                        iBackdate = 3
                    Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                        iBackdate = 4
                    Case Else ' Other days
                        iBackdate = 2
                End Select

                ' Check date
                If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                            ' Save Attachments
                    If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                    dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "CompB Report 
    UpTo" & Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                    If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                        Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                    Else
                        Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                    End If
                        
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
    objAttachment.FileName = "compb Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in a valid 
    folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                End If
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next




    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_C)

        'Check Item Class
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

            'Set as Mail Item
            Set objMailItem = objItem

        With objMailItem
            Select Case Weekday(Now)
                Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                    iBackdate = 3
                Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                    iBackdate = 4
                Case Else ' Other days
                    iBackdate = 2
            End Select

            ' Check date
            If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                ' Save Attachments
                If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "CompC  Report UpTo" & 
     Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                End If
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
    objAttachment.FileName = "CompC Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in a valid 
    folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                End If
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next


    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_D)

    'Check Item Class
    If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

        'Set as Mail Item
        Set objMailItem = objItem

        With objMailItem
            Select Case Weekday(Now)
                Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                    iBackdate = 3
                Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                    iBackdate = 4
                Case Else ' Other days
                    iBackdate = 2
            End Select

            ' Check date
            If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                ' Save Attachments
                If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "CompD Report UpTo" & 
     Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                End If
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
     objAttachment.FileName = "compd Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in a valid 
     folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                End If
                
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next




    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_E)

    'Check Item Class
    If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

        'Set as Mail Item
        Set objMailItem = objItem

        With objMailItem
            Select Case Weekday(Now)
                Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                    iBackdate = 3
                Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                    iBackdate = 4
                Case Else ' Other days
                    iBackdate = 2
            End Select

            ' Check date
            If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                ' Save Attachments
                If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "CompE  Report UpTo" & 
    Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                End If
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        

                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
     objAttachment.FileName = "compe  Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in a valid 
     folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                End If
                
            End If

        End With

    End If

    Next


     For Each objItem In objFolder.Items.Restrict(COMP_F)

    'Check Item Class
    If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then

        'Set as Mail Item
        Set objMailItem = objItem

        With objMailItem
            Select Case Weekday(Now)
                Case 7 ' Saturday: add extra day
                    iBackdate = 3
                Case 1, 2, 3 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
                    iBackdate = 4
                Case Else ' Other days
                    iBackdate = 2
            End Select

            ' Check date
            If .ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            
                ' Save Attachments
                If objAttachment.Count > 0 Then
                
                dirFolderName = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & "CompF  Report UpTo" & 
     Format(objAttachment.receivetime, "yyyy-mm")
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirFolderName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirFolderName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirFolderName)
                End If
                        
                        For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject
                        
                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting" & 
    objAttachment.FileName = "compf Report" & Format(.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")   'Put in a valid 
     folder location to store attachements

                        Next
                End If
                
            End If
            
        End With

    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're expecting anyone to go through your code and identify any issues, that's really too much code.  Is there a *specific* issue you're facing?  What is the problem here?  It's best to make your question about *one specific thing* and describe exactly what that is.

Comment: @TimWilliams you’re right it’s quite long. As part of the question, as I know some codes are repeated, I’m hoping that I can get some help. I’m stuck and am still currently searching and working out other means. I need help in simplifying the codes with the above stated criteria intact. Many thanks for reading through.

Comment: There’s a bunch of refactoring which would make your code more maintainable (I can take a look later) but likely that will not make it any *faster* - it will still be doing the same work.

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes, please. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm certain there are others who would make use of your provided answer. As long as it satisfies the criteria. The other part stated above:  I also need to create automation where each folder will hold files maxing 2 months only after which another folder would be created with new attachments of those months that will populate. - This i wasn't able to write the code for but would appreciate it if you could support me. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd rework this.  Compiled but not tested, so you may need to do some debugging if it doesn't work.

```
Sub SaveOutlookAttachments()

    Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox")

    ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "Scotland", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa Scotland Region Report"
    ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "North", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa North Region Report"
    ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "Midlands", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa Midlands Region Report"
    ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "London", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa London Region Report"


End Sub

Sub ProcessMails(srcFolder As Outlook.Folder, compName As String, subj As String, _
                 saveFolder As String, saveFileName As String)

    Const ROOT_FOLDER As String = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting\"

    Dim objItem As Object, objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem, dirFolderName As String
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

    For Each objItem In srcFolder.Items.Restrict(PFilter(compName, subj))
        If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then 'Check Item Class

            Set objMailItem = objItem 'Set as Mail Item

            If ProcessThisMail(objMailItem) Then
                With objMailItem

                    dirFolderName = ROOT_FOLDER & saveFolder & _
                                    Format(objMailItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm") & "\"

                    EnsureSaveFolder dirFolderName

                    Debug.Print "Message:", objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject

                    For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                        Debug.Print , "Attachment:", objAttachment.Filename

                        objAttachment.SaveAsFile dirFolderName & _
                              saveFileName & Format(objMailItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                    Next

                End With
            End If 'processing this one
        End If 'is a mail item
    Next objItem
End Sub

'return a filter for company and subject
Function PFilter(sCompany, sSubj)
    PFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@" & sCompany & "%'" & _
              "AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%" & sSubj & "%'"
End Function

'Abstract out the rules for when a mail is processed
Function ProcessThisMail(theMail As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
    Dim iBackdate As Long
    If theMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        Select Case Weekday(Now)
            Case 7: iBackdate = 3 ' Saturday: add extra day
            Case 1, 2, 3: iBackdate = 4 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
            Case Else: iBackdate = 2 ' Other days
        End Select
        If theMail.ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
            ProcessThisMail = True 'will by default return false unless this line is reached
        End If
    End If
End Function

'ensure a subfolder exists
Sub EnsureSaveFolder(sPath As String)
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        If Not .FolderExists(sPath) Then
            .CreateFolder sPath
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome Tim. Will debug and amend accordingly. Where I struggle, I hope you wouldn't mind me posting on here for either you or anyone to help. Code is short and more manageable. Many many thanks Tim

Comment: I've been working in VBA for >20 years but wouldn't consider myself a "master".  It just builds up over time...   If there's someting else you need to do though, I would post a new question (or review some of the existing questions already here on the same topic)

Comment: I have searched and what I'm getting is FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select Workbook to Import", MultiSelect:=True). This code requires user input (for user to actively select files to open). I am aiming to automate where ONLY the last 9 downloaded files saved in different folders are coppied into one excel sheet. So somthing like this:  If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then      For FileCount = 1 To UBound(FileToOpen) 'as an array,     shNewDat.Cells.Clear   LastRow = shAll.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ...

Comment: So the final criteria would be that the downloaded attachments in their respective folders will copy themselves onto a new sheet which the new sheet will be the master file. And the next download (following day - (following the convention criteria above to exclude weekends)) would automatically populate the master file. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes probably but it's a separate question and code posted code in comments isn't very readable.  Please create a new question for this and mark this one as answered if it met your needs.

Comment: Understood, will do. I will also repost the question and hopefully, you can assist me there.

Comment: Sorry for the bother Tim, here's the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810356/re-open-attachments-from-multiple-folders-copy-contents-from-all-attachments-an      I prefer your code layout and would want to maintain. Can you please help with this?