# Open attachments from multiple folders, copy contents and save in Master File sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This task is achievable with user request such as:

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select 
Workbook to Import", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then           
    For FileCount = 1 To UBound(FileToOpen)
        shNewDat.Cells.Clear
        LastRow = shAll.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
        Set SelectedBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen(FileCount))
        SelectedBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy    
        shNewDat.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        SelectedBook.Close
        LastTempRow = shNewDat.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'locate last row in the RAWData Temp tab
```

**Situation:**
I require that the user doesn't interact with data (manually multiple selecting data). We need to access Excel files in multiple folders (limited to the day of download from Outlook) to open as soon as attachments from Outlook have been downloaded into their respective folders. Then, I need to loop through to copy contents from all selected sheets to one Excel file (Masterfile). Following day, this should continue without attachment/data being pulled through from two days or more back (only the day before).

Current code pulls attachments from Outlook and I'm stuck at this point.

I would plead that we stick to the coding convention for cleaner faster processing:

```
Sub SaveOutlookAttachments()

Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.Folders(1).Folders("Inbox")

ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "North", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa North Region Report"
ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "South", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa South Region Report"
ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "East", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa East Region Report"
ProcessMails objFolder, "compa", "West", "compa  Report UpTo", "compa West Region Report"

End Sub

Sub ProcessMails(srcFolder As Outlook.Folder, compName As String, subj As String, _
             saveFolder As String, saveFileName As String)

Const ROOT_FOLDER As String = "C:\Users\rootname\OneDrive\Desktop\VBATesting\"

Dim objItem As Object, objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem, dirFolderName As String
Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

For Each objItem In srcFolder.Items.Restrict(PFilter(compName, subj))
    If objItem.Class = Outlook.olMail Then 'Check Item Class

        Set objMailItem = objItem 'Set as Mail Item

        If ProcessThisMail(objMailItem) Then
            With objMailItem

                dirFolderName = ROOT_FOLDER & saveFolder & _
                                Format(objMailItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm") & "\"

                EnsureSaveFolder dirFolderName

                Debug.Print "Message:", objMailItem.Sender, objMailItem.ReceivedTime, objMailItem.Subject

                For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
                    Debug.Print , "Attachment:", objAttachment.Filename

                    objAttachment.SaveAsFile dirFolderName & _
                          saveFileName & Format(objMailItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                Next

            End With
        End If 'processing this one
    End If 'is a mail item
Next objItem
End Sub

'return a filter for company and subject
Function PFilter(sCompany, sSubj)
PFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '%@" & sCompany & "%'" & _
          "AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%" & sSubj & "%'"
End Function

'Abstract out the rules for when a mail is processed
Function ProcessThisMail(theMail As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
Dim iBackdate As Long
If theMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    Select Case Weekday(Now)
        Case 7: iBackdate = 3 ' Saturday: add extra day
        Case 1, 2, 3: iBackdate = 4 ' Sunday through Tuesday: add extra 2 days
        Case Else: iBackdate = 2 ' Other days
    End Select
    If theMail.ReceivedTime > DateAdd("d", -iBackdate, Now) Then
        ProcessThisMail = True 'will by default return false unless this line is reached
    End If
End If
End Function

'ensure a subfolder exists
Sub EnsureSaveFolder(sPath As String)
With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If Not .FolderExists(sPath) Then
        .CreateFolder sPath
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you follow the general approach you already have, one way to acheive this is to create a Sub which you call, passing in a File path: that sub open s the file, copies out the required data into your "master" workbook (not much detail in your post about exactly how you want to do that) and then closes the source file.  You could then call that Sub from (eg) just after your call to `objAttachment.SaveAsFile()`, since you have the path handy.

Comment: about copying the data, I can do that. I will loop through to match columns and add data to the bottom of the table. To be honest Tim, after work, I rush home to learn how to code and try to build this. If you can help me build this part, I will be really grateful and work out the rest myself. You've helped me enough as it is but your structuring is where I want to get to. I will use this structure as a means to better my self. Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ProcessMails(srcFolder As Outlook.Folder, compName As String, subj As String, _
             saveFolder As String, saveFileName As String)

    Const SUMMARY_WB As String = "C:\Path\ToYour\Summary\Workbook.xlsx"
    Dim saveAsFileName As String


    '...
    '...

    For Each objAttachment In .Attachments

        Debug.Print , "Attachment:", objAttachment.Filename
        saveAsFileName = dirFolderName & saveFileName & Format(objMailItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")

        objAttachment.SaveAsFile saveAsFileName
        CollectWorkbookInfo saveAsFileName, SUMMARY_WB      '<< collect info from the workbook you just saved

    Next

    '...
    '...

End Sub


Sub CollectWorkbookInfo(SourcePath As String, SummaryPath As String)
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbSummary As Workbook

    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath)      'source
    Set wbSummary = Workbooks.Open(SummaryPath) 'destination
    '...
    '   do your copying between wbSrc and wbSummary
    '...
    wbSrc.Close False       'don't save
    wbSummary.Close True    'save

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Tim, really appreciated. I'm sure you're a great person to know. I will perform the rest from here. Once again, many thanks :)

Comment: Hi Tim, hope you're well. Why does it give a dialogue box: Compiler error: Ambiguous name detected Process Mails?

Comment: Hi, Again Tim, So sorry to bother you. The question hasn't changed - just didn't get the answer. So after downloading files into folders (different folders based on company), 1) I need those files (recent files in folder(s)) to open automatically, then based on their column headings, paste into the Master file excel sheet.               The logic here is to gather responses from all companies& regions reporting back to me, then me collating data automatically into one source data file (the Master file). I don't think the code above answered that.

Comment: ProcessMails is the same procedure I posted in your previous question, with some slight modifications to call CollectWorkBookInfo.  I’d didn’t include the whole content - just enough to show how you combine the two